# Vue js build is failing

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I've got an existing web app made using Laravel. I'm moving my project's frontend to Vuejs. So I've modified my view `app.blade.php` to be:

```
@include('layout.header')
<div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
@include('layout.footer')
```

My `web.php` route file now is:

```
Route::get('/{any}', function() {
    return view('layout.app');
})->where('any', '.*');
```

Within `resources/js/` I have my routes file which uses Vue-router (already installed):

```
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound'
import Home from "./pages/Home"


export default {
    mode: 'history',

    routes: [
        {
            path: '*',
            component: NotFound
        },
        {
            path: '/',
            component: Home
        }
    ]
}
```

and my `app.js` file is:

```
import './bootstrap'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import routes from './routes'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router: new VueRouter(routes)
});
```

For testing purposes I created a simple `Home.vue` component located in `resources\js\pages`. This is the component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>This is home</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {}
</script>
```

but it never loads. When compiling I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                               7:54:59 PM
>
> error  in ./resources/js/pages/Home.js
>
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
>   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/Users/bigweld/Sites/championshiprecords/resources/js/pages/Home.js'
>
> @ ./resources/js/routes.js 2:0-32 10:15-19  @ ./resources/js/app.js 
>   @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

by the way, my `webpack.mix.js` is simply:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .copy('resources/images', 'public/images', true);
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close but you are missing something while importing

SO

FROM

```
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound'
import Home from "./pages/Home"
```

TO

```
import NotFound from './pages/NotFound.vue'
import Home from "./pages/Home.vue"
```

You are missing the vue extension

Comment: Nicely spotted. It's possible to configure Webpack's loaders to test for the `.vue` extension (in fact, it's the default in Vue CLI v3 builds) but from the error message, it seems the Laravel version does not have that feature.

Comment: actually i don't have much knowledge in Vue js . i am just using few components in the laravel apps that's it

Comment: Thanks, you're right. In a separate project (vue only and the one I used for learning purposes) I import without the .vue extension, that's why I assumed it'd work on the other one and never thought about it. Do you know why? The error is now gone, but I still see nothing when loading the route, any ideas?

Comment: Neve mind, I never added ```<router-view></router-view>``` in my app.blade.php file.